# Python - Can't assign to function call?

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error

I am trying to create a very basic combat feature for a text based adventure game and my issue is that I am relieving an error regarding this line in particular.

random.choice(gold_dropped) += gold

The error in question is a Syntax error: can't assign to function call error and I am stumped on what is causing the issue and how to fix it.

Any feedback at all would be greatly appreciated.

The function in where that error lies is shown below.

def combat():

```
enemy_health = (random.choice(random_enemy_Health))

enemy_attack = (random.choice(random_enemy_Attack)) 
print("You are fighting a" ,random.choice(enemies), "with an attack amount of" ,enemy_attack, "and a health amount of" ,enemy_health,".")    
while (enemy_health > 0):
    enemy_attack - health;

while (health > 0):
    attack - enemy_health;

if enemy_health == 0:
    print("The enemy has been defeated!")
    random.choice(gold_dropped) += gold

if health == 0:
    print("You have been defeated! Return back to the Hub and re-prepare yourself!")
    hub_travel()
```

Comment: You probably meant `gold += random.choice(gold_dropped)`.

Answer (score 0):

With the instruction random.choice(gold_dropped) += gold, you add the value of variable "gold" to something that "doesn't exist" (it must be an existing variable, you cannot assign something to the anonymous result of a function). That is why the python interpreter complains.

You simply need to use an intermediate variable (validity of the instruction below checked with python 3.5):

```
if enemy_health == 0:
    print("The enemy has been defeated!")
    choice_of_gold_dropped = random.choice(gold_dropped) + gold
...
```